# RSpec: stubbing SFTP - private method called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, sftp

I'm attempting to stub out SFTP in a model. Here's the model:

```
class BatchTask
  require 'net/sftp'

  def get_file_stream(host, username, password, path_to_dir, filename)
    raise ArgumentError if host.nil? or username.nil? or password.nil? or path_to_dir.nil? or filename.nil?
    file_stream = nil
    Net::SFTP.start(host, username, password) do |sftp|
      sftp.dir.glob(path_to_dir, filename) do |entry|
        # Verify the directory contents
        raise RuntimeError(true), "file: #{path_to_dir}/#{filename} not found on SFTP server" if entry.nil?
        file_stream = sftp.file.open("#{path_to_dir}/#{entry.name}")
      end
    end
    file_stream
  end

end
```

Here's the spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "SftpToServer" do
  let(:ftp) { BatchTask::SftpToServer.new }

 it "should return a file stream" do
    @sftp_mock = mock('sftp')
    @entry = File.stubs(:reads).with("filename").returns(@file)
    @entry_mock = mock('entry')
    @entry_mock.stub(:name).and_return("filename")
    @sftp_mock.stub_chain(:dir, :glob).and_yield(@entry_mock)
    Net::SFTP.stub(:start).and_yield(@sftp_mock)
    @sftp_mock.stub_chain(:file, :open).with("filename").and_yield(@file)

    ftp.get_file_stream("ftp.test.com", "user", "password", "some/pathname", "filename").should be_kind_of(IO)
  end

end
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
NoMethodError in 'SftpToServer should return a file stream'
private method `open' called for #<Object:0x10c572620>
/Users/app/models/batch_task/sftp_to_server.rb:12:in `get_file_stream'
/Users/app/models/batch_task/sftp_to_server.rb:9:in `get_file_stream'
/Users/app/models/batch_task/sftp_to_server.rb:8:in `get_file_stream'
./spec/models/batch_task/sftp_to_server_spec.rb:15:
```

I've googled this, but I can't figure out why RSpec would treat sftp.file.open as a private method...

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured what was happening - I hadn't described the open() method as part of the @sftp_mock object, so @sftp.file.open looked like a private method. Fixing this required having @sftp_mock.file return @sftp_mock, so that it could be chained to the open() method like this:

```
@sftp_mock.stub!(:file) { @sftp_mock }
@sftp_mock.should_receive(:open).with("some/pathname/filename").and_return(@file)
```

I was also missing the @file declaration...the complete spec file is:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "SftpToServer" do
  let(:ftp) { BatchTask::SftpToServer.new }

 it "should return a file stream" do
    @file = File.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/spec/files/express_checkout_tdr.csv", "r")
    @sftp_mock = mock('sftp')
    @entry = File.stubs(:reads).with("filename").returns(@file)
    @entry_mock = mock('entry')
    @entry_mock.stub(:name).and_return("filename")
    @sftp_mock.stub_chain(:dir, :glob).and_yield(@entry_mock)
    Net::SFTP.stub(:start).and_yield(@sftp_mock)
    @sftp_mock.stub!(:file) { @sftp_mock }
    @sftp_mock.should_receive(:open).with("some/pathname/filename").and_return(@file)

    ftp.get_file_stream("ftp.test.com", "user", "password", "some/pathname", "filename").should be_kind_of(IO)
  end

end
```

This other stackoverflow question helped me with this concept: [Stub chain together with should_receive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262181/stub-chain-together-with-should-receive)

Also, feel free to comment if there's a better way to mock and stub out SFTP. This spec example has gotten kinda ugly!